# Need help replacing hardcode in html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a biography page for my company's  website, and I want it to be formatted with a  of the employees' profile pictures. Each picture can then be click, which will fade the screen to gray and also display an overlay for the clicked person's profile. The problem with my code, however, is that it hardcodes with the names of each person within the  of the . How can I get this to work without using "person1", "person2", and so on inside the head, and just use "person" instead (or some better way if you guys know how)?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#showperson1").click(function(){
                    $('.person1').show("fast");
                });
                $("#hideperson1").click(function(){
                    $('.person1').hide("slow");
                });
                $("#showperson2").click(function(){
                    $('.person2').show("fast");
                });
                $("#hideperson2").click(function(){
                    $('.person2').hide("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #overlay {
                display: none; /* ensures it’s invisible until it’s called */
                position: fixed; /* makes the div go into a position that’s absolute to the browser viewing area */
                left: 50%; 
                top: 50%;
                padding: 25px;
                padding-right: 250px;           
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #222222;
                border: 10px gray;
                border-radius: 25px;
                background: #ffffff;
                height: 500px;
                width: 500px;
                z-index: 100;
                margin-top: -275px; /* negative half the size of height */
                margin-left: -400px; /* negative half the size of width */
                font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }   
            #fade {
                display: none; 
                position: fixed;
                left: 0%;
                top: 0%; 
                background-color: gray;
                -moz-opacity: 0.5; 
                opacity: .50;
                filter: alpha(opacity=50);
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 90;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width:600">
            <tr align="center">
                <td align="center">
                    <img height="100px" width="100px"
                        src="http://www.jamsadr.com/files/Professional/1fb60f23-00d5-4c43-a552-63321c9ed969/Presentation/HighResPhoto/Person-Donald-900x1080.jpg"
                        id="showperson1"
                    >
                    <div class="person1" id="fade"></div>
                    <div class="person1" align="left" id="overlay">
                        <img src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/close-button-with-rounded-corners_318-9865.jpg"
                            id="hideperson1"
                            height="25"
                            width="25"
                            style="position:absolute; right:15px; top:15px;"
                        >                   
                        <img src="http://www.jamsadr.com/files/Professional/1fb60f23-00d5-4c43-a552-63321c9ed969/Presentation/HighResPhoto/Person-Donald-900x1080.jpg"
                            height="175px"
                            width="175px"
                            style="position:absolute; right:50px; top:75px;"
                        >
                        <a href="vcard.vcf">
                            <img src="http://www.aianwpr.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/vcard_icon.png"
                                height="30px"
                                width="30px"
                                style="position:absolute; right:180px; top:275px;"
                            >
                        </a>
                        <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_parent">
                            <img src="http://stsff.org/wp-content/uploads/email-icon.png"
                                height="30px"
                                width="30px"
                                style="position:absolute; right:180px; top:322px;"
                            >
                        </a> 
                        <a href="tel:+1-800-123-4567">
                            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/igh0zt/ios7-style-metro-ui/512/MetroUI-Other-Phone-icon.png"
                                height="30px"
                                width="30px"
                                style="position:absolute; right:180px; top:367px;"
                            >
                        </a>
                        <p style="position:absolute; left:625px; top:265px;">
                            <font size="2">
                                vCard<br/><br/>
                                Email<br/><br/>
                                Phone<br/><br/>
                            </font>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            biography for person1
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <br/><strong>Person1</strong><br/>Person1 Title
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <img height="100px" width="100px"
                        src="http://www.firstpersonarts.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Soledad-new-headshot-7-073.jpg"
                        id="showperson2"
                    >
                    <div class="person2" id="fade"></div>
                    <div class="person2" align="left" id="overlay">
                        <img src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/close-button-with-rounded-corners_318-9865.jpg"
                            id="hideperson2"
                            height="25"
                            width="25"
                            style="position:absolute; right:15px; top:15px;"
                        >                   
                        <img src="http://www.firstpersonarts.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Soledad-new-headshot-7-073.jpg"
                            height="175px"
                            width="175px"
                            style="position:absolute; right:50px; top:75px;"
                        >
                        <a href="vcard.vcf">
                            <img src="http://www.aianwpr.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/vcard_icon.png"
                                height="30px"
                                width="30px"
                                style="position:absolute; right:180px; top:275px;"
                            >
                        </a>
                        <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_parent">
                            <img src="http://stsff.org/wp-content/uploads/email-icon.png"
                                height="30px"
                                width="30px"
                                style="position:absolute; right:180px; top:322px;"
                            >
                        </a> 
                        <a href="tel:+1-800-123-4567">
                            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/igh0zt/ios7-style-metro-ui/512/MetroUI-Other-Phone-icon.png"
                                height="30px"
                                width="30px"
                                style="position:absolute; right:180px; top:367px;"
                            >
                        </a>
                        <p style="position:absolute; left:625px; top:265px;">
                            <font size="2">
                                vCard<br/><br/>
                                Email<br/><br/>
                                Phone<br/><br/>
                            </font>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            biography for person2
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <br/><strong>Person1</strong><br/>Person1 Title
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Classes, by definition, describe a set of like elements. If you're incrementing classes, there's a good chance you're using them wrongly.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t53qf1hc/

Comment: what do you mean by this? person within the of the .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes and the html structure instead.

Replace your `id="show/hideperson#"` with `class="showperson" and class="hideperson"` then use jQuery to select elements based on html structure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showperson").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.person').show("fast");
    });
    $(".hideperson").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.person').hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t53qf1hc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the same three class values on your elements, and use DOM traversal to target the appropriate ones in your click function. No need for data attributes, extra classes, or any other complication.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/a5hof5g1/

```
$('.show').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.person, .fade').show('fast');
});

<img class="show" ... />
<div class="fade"> ... </div>
<div class="person"> ... </div>
```

You probably don't need a fade element for each instance, though. Put one somewhere near the end of your page and call it by ID.

Also, I've found it to be good practice to use single quotes (apostrophes) for JS, and double-quotes for HTML. You won't have inadvertent string truncation and you eliminate the need for escape characters in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is give each "show" div a .show class and give it a data attribute of the person it is responsible for showing.

HTML

```
<div class="show" data-person="person1">Show</div>
```

JS

```
$('.show').click(function(e) {
    var person = $(this).data('person');
    $('#' + person).show();
}
```

Repeat this for close as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to the img or the element clicked, and then extract that information and put it in the overlay. That way you can do it dynamically

```
<img src='imagen.jpg' class='person1' data-person-name="Mario Fernandez"/>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".person1").click(function(e){
                $('#overlay').show("fast");
                $('#overlay .name').html($(e.target).data('name'));
            });

 </script>
```